# Cross compiling gtk application from macOS to windows?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cross-compiling, gtk3

I've seen answers from linux to windows, but how do I do macOS to windows. I have a gtk3 application and I tried to use `` i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o main  `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 `` thus far, but it gives:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.72.3/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.24.34/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.24.34/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.24.34/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.72.3/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:75:1: error: ‘uid_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘pid_t’?
   75 | uid_t            g_credentials_get_unix_user      (GCredentials    *credentials,
      | ^~~~~
      | pid_t
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.72.3/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:79:52: error: ‘uid_t’ has not been declared
   79 |                                                    uid_t           uid,
      |
```

Comment: By cross-compiling, you mean you want to be able to compile the application in MacOS/X, and then run the resulting executable in Windows?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, I want to make a .exe on my Mac and run it on windows. I've done it before but gtk3 is different the normal way doesn't work.

Comment: Though GTK3 can be build on Windows I don't think `g_credentials_get_unix_user()` will exist in the Windows build. You should make sure your application doesn't have any UNIX specifics in order to be able to port it.